# $_POST variable not passing properly

Tags: php, html, http-post

So, I have 3 different web-pages that to passes variable to the next web-page.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['transdate'] = $date_name;
```

**Next page:**

```
echo $_SESSION['transdate'];
```

Yes, I know session can be used to achieve the similar functionality. But, after trying the code above it says "Undefined variable: _SESSION". Yet, I made sure it has a proper name.

So now I'm trying through $_POST, it's not showing undefined variable. But, it's not showing any results.

### First form:

```
$datePicker .= "<input class='datepicker' type='text' name='datepicker'>";
```

The variable in the second form which was fetched from the first one is completely working.

### Second form:

**PHP:**

```
$date_name $_POST['datepicker'];
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];
$date = date('Y-m-d: H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="inquiry.php" method="post">
    <input name="schedule" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $schedule; ?>"
    />
    <label><font color="red">*</font> Number of Kids:</label>
    <input name="kid" style="height:30px;"
    type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Example: 1234567" pattern="[0-9]{1,11}"
    required />
    <label><font color="red">*</font> Number of Adults:</label>
    <input name="adult"
    style="height:30px;" type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Example: 1234567"
    pattern="[0-9]{1,11}" required />
    <label><font color="red">*</font> Number of Rooms:</label>
    <input name="transdate"
    type="hidden" value="<?php echo $date_name; ?>" />
    <select name="number_room">
        <?php echo $availableRooms; ?>
    </select>
    <label><font color="red">*</font> Number of Cottages:</label>
    <select name="number_cottages">
        <?php echo $availableCottages; ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="text-align:center; margin-left: 0px; ">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

While here the results are not showing.

### Third Form

```
$date = $_POST['transdate'];
$date = date('Y-m-d: H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

EDIT: [Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue1dR.jpg)

Comment: did you called session_start() in next page also?

Comment: Yes, it is still undefined.

Comment: did you corrected `$date_name $_POST['datepicker'];` in the second php file to `$date_name = $_POST['datepicker'];` ?

Comment: Yes, this is driving me nuts. 
I've been even changing variable names and input names just to make sure it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `session_start()` on **every** page.

First page:

```
session_start();

$date_name = 'whatever';

$_SESSION['transdate'] = $date_name;
```

Second page:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['transdate'];
```

Comment: @KyoYamagata the session variable is undefined? Shouldn't be. The code above is perfectly valid :)

Comment: Make sure `session_start()` is **before anything**. It should be the first thing after the PHP tag. It looks like you have it in an if statement.

Comment: Still not working, I have placed it above all
I even opened a new php tag just to make sure.